# Why SSRS Reports stop returning data after half hour of sitting?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have a ton of SSRS reports deployed.  About a month ago we started to see a problem where if a user opened a report, let it sit for half an hour or more, then put in a parameter and hit the "View Report" button, the report would spin and spin.  The user would think it was doing something but in the end they get a white screen with nothing in it.  If they use the browser refresh or re-open the report, everything would work fine again.

Again, this only started happening about a month ago.  Any ideas?

We are on Windows Domain, use Windows Auth, SQL Server 2017, SSRS 2016.

Comment: I'm gonna go with server resources. I just so happened to have an SSRS report up that had been run yesterday and haven't touched it since. I changed one param, and no issue. But we also just got a brand new server with 512GB ram, so we're not hurting for resources. At first, it made me think of a time out or caching issue, but could be related to server resources ultimately. If you've added more and more reports, it could potentially explain the gradual shift. But I'm spitballing.

Comment: Are you able to monitor the SSRS log files for activity while submitting one of these spinning reports? I'm guessing the request is not even getting to SSRS. Also spitballing here but I'd be looking for network issues like one of those stupid re-encrypting proxy appliances from BCSI.